# MVC Get javascript to validate before normal post (not ajax)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I can't get my javascript to be called before the form is submitted so I can do some client side validation. I also want to alter the value in txtVideo before it's submitted to the controller. Is there a nice way to do that or would I have to set a hidden field (which I guess I consider a little hacky but will work)

```
@section scripts{
<script>
    $("#VideoForm").submit(function () {
        alert("test");

    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", name="VideoForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin:5px auto; text-align: center;">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/OMB_Logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin: 5px auto;">
            <input type="text" name="txtVideo" class="form-control input-lg" style="margin: 0px auto" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin: 5px auto; text-align: center;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit Video" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: what is this weird selector `$('VideoForm')` ? makes no sense

Comment: Thought that was how you selected a control? VideoForm is the name of my form.

Comment: you've changed it now I see. are you sure it has an ID like that? it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Ah needed to change name= to id= in the form. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: you're welcome. always check your selector works if things seems not to work..you can just do it in your browser's console inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Form Validation plugin:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

and do like this in form submit event:

```
$('form[name="VideoForm"]').submit(function(){

$(this).validate();
// or
$('form[name="VideoForm"]').validate();
});
```

and one more thing, you are setting form name atttribute to Video Form and in jquery selector, you are using id, its wrong.

If you want to apply id selector do like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", 
                       "Home", 
                        FormMethod.Post, 
                  new { @class = "form-horizontal", 
                        role = "form", 
                        id="VideoForm" }))

{
}
```